# How do I save image produced by asciiview?

Tags: command-line, bash

When I run command asciiview image.jpg I'm able to view image in the terminal and quit browser using q key. I've tried different ways to redirect the output of the `asciiview image.jpg` to the console output (stdout) or save in the file such as `asciiview image.jpg > ascii_art.txt` or `asciiview -driver stdout image.jpg > ascii_art.txt` but I didn't get a result as I'm expecting.

In the first case, I had to manually press Ctrl+C to get a proper image in the text file, in the second case I didn't get anything meaningful that would resemble the picture.

Have anyone ideas how I can save image produced by asciiview directly to file or display it in the console output without entering browser and having to press q key?

Comment: I wonder if you would be better served by using the application jp2a? Simple syntax example: `jp2a test.jpg --output=test.txt` with many permutations available. asciiview / aview seem to struggle with output to file. Conversion from other image formats is easily done with imagemagick and pipes...